# Match 2 arrays with rows' values

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write a code that uses two 1D arrays and based on the match with the value on the row, it should return the value in the 3rd array.

This is what I want to do:

In Sheet1, I have 3 columns with data on ID, Name, and Amount with a number of rows of uncertain size:
[image]

In Sheet2, I have already the columns with data on ID and Name but I don't have the data on Amount:

[image]

Therefore, I want to run the code that will match the arrays with ID and Name data in Sheet1 with ID and Name data in Sheet2 and then, return the respective Amount data to Sheet2 as it is in Sheet1.

This is the desired outcome in Sheet2 after running the code, i.e. the data in column Amount are returned based on the match with arrays on ID and Name in Sheet1:
[image]

This is my code that does not run as it should:

```
Sub ArrayMatch()

Dim r As Long
Dim d As Long
Dim w_output As Worksheet
Dim w1 As Worksheet
Dim intLastRow As Integer
Dim IntLastCol As Integer
Dim arrName() As Variant
Dim arrID() As Variant
Dim arrrAmoun() As Variant

d = 8

With ThisWorkbook
    Set w1 = .Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set w_output = .Sheets("Sheet2")
End With

'***********************************
'Assign arrays

With w1

    intLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    IntLastCol = .Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    arrID = .Range(.Cells(4, 1), .Cells(intLastRow, 1))
    arrName = .Range(.Cells(4, 3), .Cells(intLastRow, 2))
    arrAmoun = .Range(.Cells(4, 4), .Cells(intLastRow, 3))

    For r = 1 To UBound(arrID, 1)
        If Len(arrID(r, 1)) > 0 Then
            d = d + 1
                If w_output.Cells(d, 1) = arrID(r, 1) Then
                    If w_output.Cells(d, 2) = arrName(r, 1) Then
                       w_output.Cells(d, 4) = arrAmoun(r, 1)
                    End If
                End If
        End If
    Next r

End With

End Sub
```

My code does not return anything, I can assume that it is because I am comparing the arrays from sheet1 with rows in sheet 2 which is not comparative in the size, but I don't know how to do in another way.
I will appreciate any help.

Comment: It appears that the Shield number is always **11** less than the ID number.  Is this true ???

Comment: Do you need VBA? If I understand this correctly, you could use a [multiple criteria Index/Match](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/)

Comment: Yes, I want VBA, that's why I have written my code that didn't work. No Index, I would like to use arrays.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent: It does not matter what the value is. It matters how to match them in the respective columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modified your code to include an inner loop to check for ID and name in `w_output` sheet (it could also be done with `Find`). Tested with makeshift data. However there are other (more efficient) ways to achieve the same goal.

```
Sub ArrayMatch()

Dim r As Long
Dim d As Long
Dim w_output As Worksheet
Dim w1 As Worksheet
Dim intLastRow As Long            ' Modified to long
Dim IntLastRow1 As Long           ' Modified to long
Dim arrName() As Variant
Dim arrID() As Variant
Dim arrrAmoun() As Variant

'd = 8

With ThisWorkbook
    Set w1 = .Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set w_output = .Sheets("Sheet2")
End With

'***********************************
'Assign arrays

With w1

    intLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    IntLastRow1 = w_output.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arrID = .Range(.Cells(4, 1), .Cells(intLastRow, 1))
    arrName = .Range(.Cells(4, 3), .Cells(intLastRow, 3))
    arrAmoun = .Range(.Cells(4, 4), .Cells(intLastRow, 4))

    For r = 1 To UBound(arrID, 1)
        If Len(arrID(r, 1)) > 0 Then
            For d = 9 To IntLastRow1     ' Modified to for loop for w_output sheet
                If w_output.Cells(d, 1) = arrID(r, 1) Then
                    If w_output.Cells(d, 2) = arrName(r, 1) Then
                    w_output.Cells(d, 4) = arrAmoun(r, 1)
                    Exit For            ' added once found and amount  put in place
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next r

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, did you test it in excel? Because when running it, nothing happens at all, no returned, values, no even any msgBox. How come?

Comment: Sorry I tested it with Names in column 2 of sheet1. But since Names are in Column 3 of Sheet1, assignment of Array `arrName` going wrong. Retested it with new assignment (and with name in column 3 of Sheet1)  and again found working fine. Edited the answer.

Comment: I didn't realize that either. Thank you very much works smoothly :) Cheers !